# RESTful API and versioning in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, api, rest, doctrine, zend-framework2

I created a RESTful API in Zend Framework 2.1 but I still don't know what is the best approach to make versioning for this API. I also use the doctrine as a model part of my app. I'd like to have links like that:

- api.name-of-my-project.com/v1/products
- api.name-of-my-project.com/v1/products/123

where `v1` describes the version of API.

So far I already created API without versioning and I also have some ideas about how to create versioning but first I'd like to know your opinions about this problem. What should I do to separate controllers and maybe other classes from different versions and how to manage the routing? By the way I think that I am not really interested about creating another module because I already have module like `API`.

The final app should be able to work with "many" versions of API. I'd like to also inherit some functionality from older version of API in my new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with zf2 routing array in your module config
 Map routes with v1 to versiononecontroller and v2 to versiontwocontroller

Comment: I would personally use modules for that. Store each version in a v1/, v2/, v3/ modules and route it appropriately. Obviously only those controllers (apis) that have implementations for those versions should live in there.